# Hex string to binary in webApp

Tags: c#, hex, arrays, data-conversion

I have a code that converts hex string to binary! On WinForm app
it works like a charm! But if I try to implement it in aspx something strange
happens. The file that should be half of size from hexstring file just keeps 
growing and growing without an end. Allso, if I stop debugging it stays highjacked
in VS2010 and I can't delete it without completly shutting down the VS2010.

The method for conversion goes like this:

```
 public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
    {
        int NumberChars = hex.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return bytes;
    }
```

and the code:

```
string FileName1 = (@"Some HEX text File");                        
using (StreamReader sr1 = File.OpenText(FileName1))
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("New Binary File", FileMode.Append)))
    {         
      string hexString = (sr1.ReadLine());
      while (hexString != null)
            {
               bw.Write(StringToByteArray(hexString));         
            }
                bw.Close();
    }
```

So, to resume, this works in winFormApp and it doesn't in WebApp. Why? I realy need it to work in WebApp. Thank You.

Comment: You use FileMode.Append in your code, so new data is appended

Comment: @Simon Mourier If You look again that's what I did.

Comment: This is not a suggestion from me, this is a fact. Since you use Append, the file *will* grow.

Comment: @Simon Mourier True, but I have to append because I read Hex file line by line and append it converted to binary. It works with WinformApp. Why it dosn't work with aspx?

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve this?  Perhaps it's being called multiple times (e.g. multiple users hitting that web page?) I'd put a breakpoint on your outer code, e.g. 'while (hexString != null)' or the start of that method, just to see if that is the case.